# Can Amos SEM deal with binary dependent variable?

Tags: spss, structural-equation-modeling, amos

Hi I'm doing a SEM using AMOS. The outcome is the success of consumer satisfaction, which is measured by 2 questions.

1. How satisfied are you? (1-7)
2. How likely would like to recommend ? (1-10)

If score for Q1>5 and Q2>7, the outcome is positive and the dependent variable = 1. But I read that the assumption of SEM includes that the endogenous variable has to be continuously distributed. Can Amos handle this type of binary variable? If not is there anything I could do?

I get the assumption infomation here:
http://www.researchgate.net/publictopics.PublicPostFileLoader.html?id=551bcf4cd2fd6424088b45e4&key=a36a33c0-acf9-4e5e-9d0a-cd4a294cc4f0

Can anyone help me? Thanks!!!